# Too direct or not

Tags: grammar

Somebody told me that she is very direct, most of the time. So that made me think that she might not be very subtle most of the time. But then I was asked this question, "why can't I be subtle and direct"?

I was kinda stunned, and I cannot imagine or find in the definition of direct, that you can't be subtle if you claim to be direct. So am I right about this?

Cause if I think somebody is ugly, I would say that person is ugly, so I am direct. But if I say I don't think that person is very pretty, I am just being nice instead of direct.

Comment: I could imagine someone being direct yet subtle by using a metaphor, or a double-entendre, or an inside joke. Difficult and up for debate on a case-by-case basis, but not entirely undoable I don't think. Subtlety as their gift paper, a sharp knife as the gift. That said, the whole point of the question you've been asked is to make you stop and think. Can these things be combined, why or why not. Can't I be a heavy smoker but still a good footballer. Can't I be a politician yet not a liar. It's thought-provoking, is the whole point of them asking.

Comment: I agree with last commenter that being subtle and direct at the same time is pretty complex. On the other hand tt's easy for someone to be subtle and direct if they exhibit the behaviours at different times.

Comment: Thank you guys for thinking along and for giving me more insight :) It really helped.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Merriam-Webster gives *straightforward* as a synonym for [*direct*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/direct#h2), and it gives *crafty* as a synonym for [*subtle*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subtle). These senses are not mutually exclusive, although they may commonly be thought so.

You can certainly be direct about *one* thing while being subtle about *something else* at the same time.

Stage magicians to this all the time as part of their misdirection. They are blatant and direct about something obvious while subtly manipulating something unseen.

Or, let's say you are in therapy to help you deal with your emotional reactions. The therapist raises their voice and says things to you in a very direct and straightforward manner designed to test your control. Whether you lose your control or not, what's happening at a more subtle level is that they are observing your reactions.

So, directness can, itself, be part of a subtle manipulation. You can be direct at one level while also being subtle at a different level.

Even at the *same* level, there can be behaviour that exists in a grey area between the two. A sweater can be an aquamarine shade that, depending on perspective, is green or blue or both. Similarly, when somebody has done something, and the way they've done it exhibits qualities of both directness and subtlety, it can be considered as both direct and subtle.